# WebGL builds are not supported on mobile devices error even though it isn't a mobile device

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, webgl, unity-webgl

On [our website](https://inf-431-21g-sg5.iet-gibb.net/wordpress/tictactoe/index.html) where I uploaded a game builded with WebGL from Unity.

[image]

I did never add any touch or mobile controls. But when I try to open the TicTacToe game it shows the error. But if I try to open my [Tetris Game](https://inf-431-21g-sg5.iet-gibb.net/wordpress/tetris/index.html) it works just fine.

[image]

How and why?

Btw I went into player Settings, and removed the Brotli Compression Format in both of those. Elsewise not even the Tetris one would work.

Thank's in advance for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What exactly said it couldnt run the game. Ive seen safari claim it cant do a 3d game but can 2d

Comment: I can actually reproduce this with the links in the question on my smartphone ... @BugFinder and others ;) Of course I have no clue whatsoever what exactly is producing the output in the first link (the one that is failing)

Comment: I was so free to add my screenshots so also people on a PC can see the outcome ;) ... Note that the second link works for me, however if I set my tab to **not** be "Desktop" then I get a popup message with the same text .. it still loads after that though.

Comment: I just confirmed the same behavior also on the PC and vote to reopen this .. it would still be good if you could add any additional information

Comment: I will take the question down, and ask it again when I got more information. The code is not written by me. It's from someone in my team and my job is it to get it onto the website. So when I got more code I'll post another question.

Comment: I was able to solve the Error by myself, I don't know why it happened but I had to change the compression from Brotli to none. Then it somehow worked. In another game I had to change the input from a click to a space and in the last game which wasn't working I just had to rebuild it, I don't know why it works now but it's solved